# Setting path on VS command prompt

Tags: c

I'm new to coding. I have Visual Studio 2019 and am doing tutorials to learn.
The command prompt is: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\community> . When I try to go to a file, my entire community folder appears. How can I set the path to something else that allows me to go to the file I want?  Example: mkdir projects>cd projects>mkdir helloworld>cd helloworld>code .

I tried a couple times with no change.

Comment: You can't create folders or files under `C:\Program Files`, because only administrators can write to that folder. Your files belong under your user folder. It might be a good idea to learn to use your OS before you start trying to work with it from a command line.

Comment: This can be a pain with the VS Developers Command Prompt. One way to do it is to navigate the menu and find the "VS Developers Command Prompt" and then right-click "Properties" for the shortcut and fill in the `"Start in:"` directory with the one you want. I use `\Users\me` so `source` for VS is available or `Documents\dev` for the rest of the source files. (note: there was a Bug on this with MS within the last 6 months, so there were changes late VS17 which should be in VS19 to help with this.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I did what you suggested and it worked. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How are you starting your VS 2019?  After  you install it, you should have a item "Visual Studio 2019" *with a purple icon* next to it.  It is below where you have the developer prompt.  After you have made your directory, use *that* to start VS.

Click on "Create a new project".  On the next screen, you specify you want to create a C/C++ console application or whatever.  On the following screen, you can specify whatever directory where want your solution to be.

If this answers your question, click the check mark to the left of this answer to indicate the problem has been solved.